# Material nested tree that support drag and drop for angular 5

Tags: angular, tree, angular-material

I’m finding a library that can build a nested tree like this https://tina-material-tree.firebaseapp.com/nested-tree.
However, it cannot build the tree with drag and drop content.

Not sure if anyone knows a similar lib like this that supports drag and drop.

Comment: Off topic. You'll have more luck finding one if you use the right term: **drag** and drop.

Comment: Thanks! I updated the summary of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://angular2-tree.readme.io/docs
Try using this.You might need to update the css for material theme

Answer (score 6):

Here's drag and drop implemented on a Material tree **without** the CDK in material 7: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-draggable-mat-tree

And here's drag and drop implemented on a Material tree **with** the CDK in material 7: https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-tree-with-drag-and-drop.

I did a detailed write-up how this was accomplished [here](https://medium.com/briebug-blog/angular-implementing-drag-and-drop-in-a-material-tree-f96b9fe40f81).

Comment: The question is about drag & drop with a _nested_ tree, but these examples use a flat tree.

Comment: @Trevor the nested and flat material trees both accomplish the same UI with a different markup structure. It's not clear if the OP has a reason or not for using the nested style, so using the flat style should be an option

Answer (score -3):

Have a look at [this Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-tree-nested). Also these [slides from NgConf 2018](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1BoJ-jq-O9zQHAps7LVciiiH9WI9dDqqv-LAlQ6iMh5o/edit#slide=id.g38348a6ff8_0_0).

Hope that helps.

Comment: That's just a material tree, it doesn't have drag and drop